# F4 on file explorer

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

Does anyone know the logic of what links show up in the list on file explorer when F4 is pressed? 
It seems like not all recently visited locations appear?

Comment: It the places you actually typed into the address bar to navigate to, listed in reverse-chronological order.

Comment: hi techie007! I've tried but have not been able to get addresses I have typed to appear on the F4 list. I do note currently that addresses I cut and paste in "save as" dialog boxes do appear in the list. Not sure about other circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft intends to generate suggestions based on the directories you traverse through the most (Microsoft does not make this explicitly known on what criteria they do this on but this is the main reason).

If you want to change it there's a solution, which gives you full control over the typed paths for the File Explorer.

Go to Run (Windows key + R together), and enter: regedit

You should now see a new Registry Editor window pop up. In the left pane of the window, navigate by expanding tree views through like so: HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > Explorer, then click TypedPaths.

You should see url1, url2, and so on, to the right pane. You can change these by double-clicking an entry, then entering a string that represents the file path of what you use most frequently.